# How can I view watchers for a project?

Tags: jira

I am a Jira admin. For some reason, in one of our projects, anytime a new issue is created there is one person that is automatically added as a watcher. I'm trying to determine why this is happening. Can you watch entire projects? If so, how? Also, as an administrator, how can I see who is watching a particular project?

If you cannot watch a project (which based on my searches seems to be the case) then why is this user being added as a watcher for all new issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the user has an automation rule set up to add himself as a watcher for any issues created GLOBALLY.

Comment: One mystery solved, now the only question is WHY? :)

Comment: Maybe he just wants to get informed about all changes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If a user becomes a watcher, the user can get notifications on certain events, which are defined for watchers in the project notification scheme. That is why you should not add the default user as a watcher, you can create a new role and call it "Default Watchers". Then define this role for the same events as for watchers in the project notification scheme. Add your default users to this role. Users in this role will have the same functionality as if they were watchers for issues.